# Return the incremented value after recursiv call of the method

Tags: java

I am trying to  return the depth of the string in the radix tree after finding the string in the radix tree but I am always getting the value `2`.

How can I keep storing the value of counter after incrementing it and get the recursiv method `depth(nextNodeEdge, restString)` called several time?

**Code:**

```
private int depth(TrieNode node, String s) {
    int count = 1;

    String communsubString = checkEdgeString(node.getNext(), s);
    String restString = s.substring(communsubString.length());
    if (node.getNext() != null && !node.getNext().isEmpty()) {
        for (TrieNode nextNodeEdge : node.getNext()) {
            if (nextNodeEdge.getEdge().equals(communsubString)) {
                count++;
                if (!restString.isEmpty()) {
                    count = depth(nextNodeEdge, restString);

                } else {
                 System.out.println("Found");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return count;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the returned value of `depth(nextNodeEdge, restString)`? Add it to `count`?

Comment: `count` never takes on a value other than `1` or `2`. If you want to measure the depth of a node during a recursive call you will need to pass the *current depth* as a parameter or increment the returned depth value. Currently, `depth()` doesn't know the depth of the node it is called with, so it also cannot return it.

Comment: Have you tried changing `count = depth(...)` to `count += depth(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could just change:

```
               count = depth(nextNodeEdge, restString);
```

to

```
               count += depth(nextNodeEdge, restString);
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work.I am still  getting 2 as returned value of the method

Comment: @Robin - then `restString.isEmpty()` must be returning `true` always.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is to make your count [Mutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Use a `Mutable<Integer>` as your count and pass it up the recusrion stack.

```
class Mutable<T> {
    T it;
    public Mutable(T it) {
        this.it = it;
    }
    public T getIt() {
        return it;
    }
    public void setIt(T it) {
        this.it = it;
    }
}
private int depth(TrieNode node, String s) {
    return depth(new Mutable<Integer>(0), node, s).getIt();
}
private  Mutable<Integer> depth(Mutable<Integer> count, TrieNode node, String s) {
    count.setIt(count.getIt() + 1);
    String communsubString = checkEdgeString(node.getNext(), s);
    String restString = s.substring(communsubString.length());
    if (node.getNext() != null && !node.getNext().isEmpty()) {
        for (TrieNode nextNodeEdge : node.getNext()) {
            if (nextNodeEdge.getEdge().equals(communsubString)) {
                count.setIt(count.getIt() + 1);
                if (!restString.isEmpty()) {
                    depth(count, nextNodeEdge, restString);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I test this solution I am getting 6 instead of 3 (node root + parent node + child).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. I needed to add `break` after this line `count += depth(nextNodeEdge, restString);` and in the else block `count++;`

**Code**

```
private int depth(TrieNode node, String s) {

   int  count = 1;
    String communsubString = checkEdgeString(node.getNext(), s);
    String restString = s.substring(communsubString.length());
    if (node.getNext() != null && !node.getNext().isEmpty()) {
        for (TrieNode nextNodeEdge : node.getNext()) {
            if (nextNodeEdge.getEdge().equals(communsubString)) {
                if (!restString.isEmpty()) {
                    count += depth(nextNodeEdge, restString);
                    break;

                } else {
                 System.out.println("Found");
                 count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }       
    return count;
}
```